# How can I order a dictionary by its values?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I am working on a data analysis project and I am trying to order my results in descending format, the first time I had a similar issue, I used `sorted(dictt.items(), key= lambda x: x[1])` and it worked fine. Now, I am having an error of type: "AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'".

What am I doing wrong?

[Actual output but I want it sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/136xO.png)

Comment: This is a dictionary: `{'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3}` and this is a set: `{'one', 1, 'two', 2, 'three', 3}`. `dictt` is a set, not a dictionary

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. I am new to all of these. I still get carried away.

Answer (score -1):

There is a special collection for what you are trying to do called OrderedDict:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

The problem is that sorting the way you did returns a set of items instead of a dict and you have to turn it into a dict again. However, the standard dict doesn't keep track of entry order for efficiency reasons, so if you really want that, just plug the set of items into an OrderedDict like so:

```
myOrderedDict =  OrderedDict(sorted(dictt.items()))
```

Comment: That won’t work, as in the question it is stated that `dictt.items()` raises an attribute error.